# Creating an entry as item list from another document library

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, development, csom

I have two document libraries. Whatever is in document library A, I would like to get an entry in library B as item list with the following properties (Name and itemCode).

Comment: You want to have it as one off operation or ongoing?

Comment: Ongoing, I need to be able to call my function and reuse it again.

Comment: what is itemCode? did you mean the item ID?

Comment: No, it is the code of products.

Answer (score 0):

For your case I would suggest you to create a sharepoint designer workflow that would copy the item from library A to library B and save the necessary data you need in library B.